# (newbie here) Range-based for loops in functions not working (C++)

Tags: for-loop

I've been doing some C++ exercises and I stumbled upon this one problem with C++ **for loops**, which is a relatively new topic to me. I decided to make a function that takes an **array of integers** and provide a certain number, whether it is the maximum value, minimum value, the average of all numbers.

So I thought it would be a lot easier to make this for loop which doesn't take the array size at all! But... **My compiler didn't like my idea**. See the code below please (the functions are written in Portuguese, but it doesn't really matter at all):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <random>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

void juradosLegais(int v[]);
float notasGrandes(int v[]);
int piorNota(int v[]);
int melhorNota(int v[]);
float getMedia(int v[]);
void storeValues(int v[]);

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");

    int notas[5];
    storeValues(notas);
    cout << "A maior nota foi " << melhorNota(notas) << " e a pior foi " << piorNota(notas) << "..." << endl;
    cout << "A média foi de " << getMedia(notas) << "." << endl;
    cout << notasGrandes(notas) << "% dos jurados foram legais." << endl;
    juradosLegais(notas);

    return 0;
}

void juradosLegais(int v[]) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int n : v ) {
        if (n == melhorNota(v))
            cout << "O jurado " << ++count << " foi bem legal com o atleta!" << endl;
    }
}

float notasGrandes(int v[]) {
    int soma = 0;
    int count = 0;
    for (int n : v[]) {
        if (n >= 8) {
            soma++;
        }
        count++;
    }
    return (soma / count) * 100;
}

int piorNota(int v[]) {
    int pior = v[0];
    for (int n : v[]) {
        n < melhor ? melhor = n;
    }
    return pior;
}

int melhorNota(int v[]) {
    int melhor = v[0];
    for (int n : v[]) {
        n > melhor ? melhor = n;
    }
    return melhor;
}

float getMedia(int v[]) {
    float sum = 0;
    int count = 0;
    for (int n : v[]) {
        sum += n;
        count++;
    }
    return sum / count;
}

void storeValues(int v[]) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int n : v[]) {
        cout << "Nota do jurado #" << ++count << ": ";
        cin >> n;
    }
}
```

And what the compiler says? These things:

```
error C3312: no callable 'begin' function found for type 'int []' (33)
error C3312: no callable 'end' function found for type 'int []' (33)
error C2065: 'n': undeclared identifier (34)
error C2059: syntax error: ']' (42)
error C2059: syntax error: '<end Parse>' (42)
```

Help me... please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If my memory serves me right, builtin arrays (like `int notas[5];`) don't work because they don't keep track of their size and don't have member functions (like `begin` and `end`) which are required for the range based `for` loops to work. Instead use the standard library [`array`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/array/array/) class to do this and pass it in. Then your `for` loops should work. So instead of:

```
int notas[5];
```

You would do:

```
std::array<int, 5> notas;
```

And instead of declaring your functions like this:

```
 void juradosLegais(int v[])
```

You could declare them like this:

```
 template <class arraytype>
 void juradosLegais(arraytype v)
 {
     ...
 }
```

Or this:

```
 void juradosLegais(std::array<int, 5> v)
 {
     ...
 }
```

Obviously, be sure to include the `array` header like so:

```
#include <array>
```

Better yet, don't use arrays of any sort and instead just use a `vector`. They are safer and more flexible and are generally as fast as arrays in most circumstances.